# How to solve this form action problem in code igniter?

Tags: codeigniter-3

CodeIgniter form action causes problem.

When I write below action URL without index.php it runs fine on Chrome and not on firefox

```
<form method="POST" action="Login/Loginme">
```

But When I write below action URL with index.php it does not run on chrome and run on firefox.

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php/Login/Loginme">
```

Answer (score 1):

use `site_url();`

```html
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo site_url('Login/Loginme'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base_url() followed by the controller is best practice. eg. `base_url('myController/myFunction')`